# mpdf cropmarks and bleed margins

Tags: php, mpdf

I've just started looking in to mPDF today (so it's all new too me). I'm a little stuck on as to how I can get the crop marks and bleed margins working. I can't see  them on the output PDF. Usually when I make files for printers (i.e. not an actual printer, but a print shop) I have to include bleed and crop marks since images for covers need it.
This is what I have now

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$pdfOptions = array(
    'mode'                  => 'utf-8', 
    'format'                => 'A4', 
    'orientation'           => 'P',
    'printers_info'         => true,
    'mirrorMargins'         => true,
    'bleedMargin'           => 3,
$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf( $pdfOptions );
$styles = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/css/print.css');
$content = '<div>Some content</div>';
$pdf->SetDisplayMode( 'fullpage','continuous' );
$pdf->img_dpi = 300;
$pdf->WriteHTML( $styles, 1 );
$pdf->WriteHTML( $content, 2 );
$pdf->Output( 'test.pdf', "I" );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to enable crop marks and control the document bleed in mPDF is via the [CSS parameter @page](http://mpdf.github.io/paging/using-page.html). [mPDF supports the `marks` and `size` CSS properties](http://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) which will make it easy for you to enable the crop marks and control the bleed.

The following sample code will add a 3mm bleed around the document:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => 'A4',
    'orientation' => 'P',
    'img_dpi' => 300,
]);

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('
<style>
    @page {
        size: 204mm 291mm;
        marks: crop;
    }
</style>

Content
');

$mpdf->Output();
```

If you want to add a larger bleed, reduce the values in the `size` parameter. Also, add a `margin` property to `@page` to control the margins around the print area.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've been playing around with these settings for a while now. Still trying to get a real handle on everything : )  But at least now I understand that the bleed settings don't automatically add the needed space, but rather you have to increase the size (since I want the final result to fit A4 (210x297)). So In my case I added space to make it work. Thanks again! Very helpful in getting me in the right direction  ; )

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this - remember that crop marks/bleed needs to be at the page size that the printing company will be using. So if you are trying to print an A4 pdf (which is 210mm x 297mm), the size attribute shown in Jake's answer will need to be 210 x 297 and the actual document size will need to be increased. The usual standard is about 5mm space added to all side of the document, which means that your document should be 10mm higher and 10mm wider.

As an example:

```
<?php
function generate_pdf($content, $pdf_width, $pdf_height, $bleed = false) {
    $bleed_size = 10; //5mm either side of the doc
    $width      = ($bleed ? $pdf_width + $bleed_size : $pdf_width); //if bleed - increase by 10mm
    $height     = ($bleed ? $pdf_height + $bleed_size : $pdf_height); //if bleed - increase by 10mm
    
    $mpdf       = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'mode'          => 'utf-8',
        'format'        => [$width, $height],
        'img_dpi'       => 300,

    ]);

    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

    if($bleed) {
        $content = add_bleed($content, $pdf_width, $pdf_height);
    }

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $mpdf->Output();
}


function add_bleed($content, $width, $height) {
    $bleed = '
<style>
    @page {
        size: '.$width.'mm '.$height.'mm;
        marks: crop;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
';
    return $bleed.$content;
}
```

Once the above functions are saved, you can simple use the following function to generate your pdf with crop marks.

```
<?php
generate_pdf('<h1>test</h1>', 210, 297, $bleed); //a4 == 210x297
```